# SpringBoot Hikari Connection pool - DB connections are lost (goes missing )and Get jdbc Connection Error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Im using Spring Boot With Hikari , Please find the connection details below.
As when the application runs. The connection depletes and becomes zero

```
    spring.datasource.username=test
    spring.datasource.password=test
    spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size = 100
    spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=180000
    spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=300000
    spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle= 10
```

As when application runs , Connection pool reduces and becomes Zero and we get DB exception.

Find the logs below.

```
 UT 2020-07-23 16:52:23.420 DEBUG [Test-service,,,] 13 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] 
    om.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=0, active=0, 
    idle=0, waiting=2)
    
    OUT 2020-07-23 16:51:53.419 DEBUG [Test-service,,,] 13 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] 
    com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=2, active=0, 
    idle=2, waiting=0)
    
    OUT 2020-07-23 16:51:23.418 DEBUG [Test-service,,,] 13 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] 
    com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=4, active=1, 
    idle=3, waiting=0)
    
    OUT 2020-07-23 16:50:53.418 DEBUG [Test-service,,,] 13 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] 
    om.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats 
    (total=4, active=0, 
    idle=4, waiting=0)
    
    OUT 2020-07-23 16:50:23.417 DEBUG [Test-service,,,] 13 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper]     
    com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats 
    (total=4, active=0,       idle=4, 
    waiting=0)
    Thu, Jul 23, 2020 16:49:53.417
    [APP/PROC/WEB/0]
    OUT 2020-07-23 16:49:53.416 DEBUG [Test-service,,,] 13 --- [HikariPool-1 
    sekeeper] 
    com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=4, active=0,     id le=4, waiting=0)
     Thu, Jul 23, 2020 16:49:23.416
    [APP/PROC/WEB/0]
    OUT 2020-07-23 16:49:23.416 DEBUG [Test-service,,,] 13 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] 
    com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=4, active=0,   idle=4, waiting=0)
    Thu, Jul 23, 2020 16:48:53.416
    [APP/PROC/WEB/0]
    OUT 2020-07-23 16:48:53.415 DEBUG [Test-service,,,] 13 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] 
    com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=5, active=0,     idle=5, waiting=0)
    Thu, Jul 23, 2020 16:48:23.415
    [APP/PROC/WEB/0]
    OUT 2020-07-23 16:48:23.415 DEBUG [Test-service,,,] 13 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] 
    com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=5, active=0,     idle=5, waiting=0)
    Thu, Jul 23, 2020 16:47:53.413
    APP/PROC/WEB/0]
    OUT 2020-07-23 16:47:53.412 DEBUG [Test-service,,,] 13 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] 
    com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
    Thu, Jul 23, 2020 16:47:23.411
    [APP/PROC/WEB/0]
    OUT 2020-07-23 16:47:23.410 DEBUG [Test-service,,,] 13 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] 
    com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=5, active=0,    idle=5, waiting=0)
    Thu, Jul 23, 2020 16:46:53.410
    [ APP/PROC/WEB/0]
    OUT 2020-07-23 16:46:53.410 DEBUG [Test-service,,,] 13 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] 
    com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats 
    (total=10, active=0,    idle=10, waiting=0)
    Thu, Jul 23, 2020 16:46:23.409
    [APP/PROC/WEB/0]
    OUT 2020-07-23 16:46:23.408 DEBUG [Test-service,,,] 13 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] 
    com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=10, active=0,     idle=10, waiting=0)
```

Comment: Don't see any exceptions, you need to identify why connections are leaking if it's so.

Comment: @sonus21 - i added connection leak threshold as well and dont see any connection leaks

Answer (score 0):

After checking, found some Network exception was causing this issue.

Connection Reset Exception and Socket Closed by remote host.

Was able to sort out after the network team fixed the issue.